# Methods to solve the system of non-linear differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I have the following system:
$$\begin{cases}\frac{dx}{dt} = (x+6)(x-7)(y-7)\\ \frac{dy}{dt} = (x^2-9)(y+5)\end{cases}$$

I have solved the system using the eigenvalue analysis and using 4th order Runga Kutta to get a numerical solution. 
Are there any other methods I can use to find the plots and the directions of the trajectories?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To eliminate $t,$ divide on equation by the other rendering  it into variable separable DE. . Next involve $t,y$ eliminating  $x$..

Answer (score 4):

You have

$$dx/dt = (x+6)(x-7)(y-7) \text{   and }$$
$$dy/dt = (x^2-9)(y+5).$$

Divide both equations to obtain

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{(x^2-9)(y+5)}{(x+6)(x-7)(y-7)}$$
$$\implies \dfrac{y-7}{y+5}dy= \dfrac{x^2-9}{(x+6)(x-7)}dx$$

You can try to solve this differential equation by integration to obtain

$$y(x) = f(x,c).$$

Comment: You got some factors wrong in the separation

Comment: @Dylan: Thank you!